# asp.net mvc wcf service: No parameterless constructor defined for this object - error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

Am developing an ASP.NET MVC application with Infrastructure, Repository, Service(WCF), Web. When I run my view (Index, Create, etc)
I have this error:

[parameterless image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az29j.png)

See my code below

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BPP.CCSP.Admin.Web.BPPCCSPAdminCountriesService;
namespace BPP.CCSP.Admin.Web.Controllers
{
public class CountriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICountriesService _countryService;



    public CountriesController(ICountriesService countryService)
    {
        _countryService = countryService;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Countries/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<COUNTRIES> countries = _countryService.GetCountries();
        return View(countries);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Countries/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(Int32 id)
    {
        COUNTRIES country = _countryService.GetCountry(id);
        return View(country);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Countries/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Countries/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(COUNTRIES countries)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _countryService.AddCountry(countries);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "We cannot add this country. Verify your data entries !");
        }

        return View(countries);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Product/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        COUNTRIES country = _countryService.GetCountry(id);
        return View(country);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Product/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, COUNTRIES countries)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                countries.COUNTRY_ID = id;
                _countryService.AddCountry(countries);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }

        return View();
    }

    //
    // AJAX: /Product/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        _countryService.RemoveCountry(id);

        var results = new
        {
            DeleteId = id
        };

        return Json(results);
    }
}
```

}

Index view

```
@model IEnumerable<BPP.CCSP.Admin.Web.BPPCCSPAdminCountriesService.COUNTRIES>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
   <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ACTION_STATUS)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.COUNTRY_CODE)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.COUNTRY_ID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.COUNTRY_NAME)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CREATED_BY)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CREATED_DATE)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DELETED_BY)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DELETED_DATE)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LAST_UPDATE_BY)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ACTION_STATUS)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COUNTRY_CODE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COUNTRY_ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COUNTRY_NAME)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CREATED_BY)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CREATED_DATE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DELETED_BY)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DELETED_DATE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LAST_UPDATE_BY)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>


@Html.ActionLink("Back to Index", "Index", "Home")
```

Pleaase where have I missed it.

Comment: Standard misleading message. check your DI container and make sure there are no issues when resolving `ICountriesService`. Make sure all dependencies are registered.

Comment: So how _is_ your dependency injection set up?

Answer (score 0):

You must tell asp.net mvc that you are using a DI Container to create your objects. Registration is usually done in global.asax app start event.